# Not Getting data from server

Tags: android, android-volley

I am trying to get data from server, I have done all the coding part I am getting status code is 200 (success) but not getting data.

**This is my JSON data:**

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "company_id": "8",
      "customer_id": "17",
      "driver_id": null,
      "city_id": "2",
      "vehicletype_id": "4",
      "status": "Pending",
      "source_long": "77.59505250000007",
      "source_lat": "12.9998698",
      "dest_long": "77.62877609999998",
      "dest_lat": "12.946679",
      "source": "Jayamahal, Bengaluru, Karnataka, India",
      "destination": "Ejipura Bus Stand, Ejipura Main Road, Ejipura, Bengaluru, Karnataka, India",
      "bookingtime": "2016-06-14 06:55:38"
    }
  ]
}
```

**This is my code to get data:**

```
 JsonObjectRequest jor = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, OPEN_BOOKINGS_URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                String string = null;
                JSONArray ja =null;
                try {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You are in Try Block", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ja=response.getJSONArray("data");
                    if(ja!=null)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Ja is not null with data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       for (int i=0; i<ja.length(); i++)
                       {
                           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "for loop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), jo.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tv.setText("ja is null");
                       // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ja is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                tv.setText(error.toString());
            }
        });
        rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        rq.add(jor);
    }
```

In the code I have written toast to check whether my code block is executing or not.

**I am getting data like,**

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "data": [
    {}
  ]
}
```

Comment: if the code above is exactly how your json looks like, then its not correct. Close brackets.

Comment: Actually you are getting this response in onResponse() method, so there is no error in your code. Ask the back end to put log from their side and check. Seems there is no data in data array.

Comment: @Jeeva Thanks for your replay

Comment: @JeevaNandhan When I enter the api url in the web, I am getting complete data. like I said at starting of  my question. When I try in my app it's showing null. like '{
  "status": 200,
  "data": [
    {}
  ]
}'

Comment: @SatheeshJagana:: have you tried in Postman.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the below code

```
 private void callDashboradWS() {
    AsyncTask<String, String, String> _Task = new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
        String _responseMain = "";


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Constant.showLoader(getActivity());

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            if (NetworkAvailablity.checkNetworkStatus(getActivity())) {
                try {
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
                    //  String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
                    URL url = new URL("YOURSERVICEURL));
                    System.out.println(url.toString() + " <<<");
                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) ((url.openConnection()));
                    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
                    urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
                    urlConnection.connect();


                    // Write
                    OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                    //  writer.write(query);
                    writer.close();
                    outputStream.close();

                    System.out.println("Response code :-- " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
                    int responsecode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
                    //Read

                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                    String line = null;
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println("in while");
                        sb.append(line);
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    _responseMain = sb.toString();


                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Constant.showToast("Server Error ", getActivity());
                    }
                });
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Constant.hideLoader();
            System.out.println("SIGNIN RESPONSE: " + _responseMain);

        }


    };
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        _Task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, (String[]) null);
    } else {
        _Task.execute((String[]) null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting Data from server side, there is no issue by your side..
You should check to server side why not sending data..
you did well...

Comment: When I enter the api url in the web, I am getting complete data. like I said at starting of my question. When I try in my app it's showing null. like '{ "status": 200, "data": [ {} ] }'